# Max limit for multi valued insert in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a python script which creates multi valued insert statement. In production this so big that this is forming insert into tables values () ,() value list is 2 million records. What are the issues it can cause and can this bring down database. I am worried about this

Comment: values table constructor cannot have more than 1000 rows. So you should probably split it up.

Comment: Understood, i updated the code to consume in batches. It will take a month to go in production. Mean while can this cause any issue and It able to insert around 2 and half million records. So from server side any thing it will do?

Comment: How exactly are you building the insert statement? Are you reading data from an existing table(s)?

Comment: That's not quite true, @siggemannen. When used in the context of `INSERT INTO... VALUES` it's limited. If it were `INSERT INTO... SELECT... FROM (VALUES...)` it would not be.

Comment: Iam reading from a file and preparing a list in python. Using pyodbc iam executing with insert statement with values list

Comment: Could a `BULK INSERT` be more appropriate?

Comment: @ThomA, hmm, right, i forgot about that. But it's usually still not good to have very large VALUES batches, because i think sql server takes longer and longer time to parse them properly

Comment: If you have 2K rows much less 2M rows, BULK INSERT or bcp is the appropriate solution, not writing a script with 2K rows. Never mind 2M rows

Comment: Ok. I will update the code. But any merging patch will take time. Mean while can this break database

Comment: @TurumellaAditya why are you trying to insert 2M rows like this and more importantly, *why*? `INSERT`, in any database, just isn't meant for bulk imports

Comment: No, there is no exact reason. I am not aware of fact that it comes this big in production

Comment: It won't *break* the database, but it will (likely) not be performant and could end up being a blocking operation.

Comment: Ok understood, so It will block operations on this tables until this transaction is killed or completed. Is there any other I need to worried about till code is updated

Comment: `so big` 2M rows isn't big at all. It's between "little" and "some" data. Why did you even thing of using INSERT to import 2M rows? `no exact reason` there must have been one, because that's completely different from what either the `Import Data` wizard or the documentation shows. A google search on importing data would return results on bcp, BULK INSERT, SSIS, Import Data but *never* manual INSERTs

Comment: Ok. I have insert in my python application after processing of files. At that time I did not took care of this. Now updated to insert with batch. Thanks

Comment: There's no `batch` command in Python, nor is there any way to perform bulk inserts. `Bulk` doesn't refer to batching but the bulk insert mode that uses minimal logging. Instead of writing every insert into the transaction log, the server writes entire data pages at a time. That means a *lot* fewer IO operations need to be performed. ETL jobs never insert into live tables either, they insert into staging tables that aren't locked by other connections. Once the data is loaded, it's used to update live tables

Comment: When I say batches i meant preparing values list of 250 and inserting them one by one instead of all records.

Comment: Post your actual code and explain what you're trying to do. If you use pyodbc with the `fastexecutemany` option you'll get a lot better performance. It won't be as good as `bcp`, `BULK INSERT` or .NET's SqlBulkCopy, but it will be several times faster than individual INSERTs

Comment: @TurumellaAditya `when I say` don't describe your code, post it. Others have faced the same issues as you over the last 20+ years, with Python or other languages. I repeat, the *fast* way is to use `bcp` so *why* aren't you using it? What library and driver did you use in Python? What options? Post the code

Comment: Ok sure. Will post. As of now my code is not using fast execute method. For now wanted to know can this cause serious issue in production or not. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the comment which states that max 1000 records like this. I am exactly forming insert into tables values statement

Comment: The cause is the inappropriate technique. In all databases there are bulk load tools that are faster than individual INSERTs. Inserting into a live table is always slower too, because the INSERTs will conflict with other transactions. There are techniques to handle the actual problems, and even ways to load data without interruptions using [partition switching](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching)

Comment: cursor.execute("""
                  INSERT INTO Components
                  ([Database Number],Description, [Warehouse Code],[Supplier Code], Usage, Major1, Minor1)
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                  """), input_list
cursor.commit() this is kind of insert I am forming so can this able to insert large values if it has 1000 limit

Comment: You could do a `subprocess` call to `bcp`